# Ember Data, hasMany not updating

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Can't believe something so simple is giving me so much greif! Anyway, I have two models:

```
App.Basket = DS.Model.extend({
  fruits: DS.hasMany('App.Fruit')
});

App.Fruit = DS.Model.extend({
  basket: DS.belongsTo('App.Basket')
});
```

I fetch a basket with id: 1 and don't specify any fruit_ids. Then later on I fetch a fruit with a basket_id of 1. `fruit.get('basket')` returns the basket just fine. However, `basket.get('fruits')` is empty, it never updates.

Specifying fruit_ids in the basket JSON is not an acceptable solution as in the actual real application a basket may have thousands to millions of fruit and the user won't be needing to fetch them all.

I've tried adding the following on `App.Fruit`:

```
didLoad: function() {
  this.get('basket').get('fruits').pushObject(this);
}
```

Which works fine for the first load. However, if ember-data attempts to fetch the data again then you just get:

`` Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `loadedData` on <App.Fruit:ember353:3> while in state rootState.loaded.updated.uncommitted. Called with undefined ``

Changing `didLoad` to:

```
didLoad: function() {
  this.get('basket').get('fruits').pushObject(this);
  this.get('stateManager').send('becameClean');
  this.get('stateManager').send('finishedMaterializing');
}
```

Removes all errors. However, didLoad is never called again even when ember attempts to refetch the data (e.g after visiting another route and back again).

Spent a good few hours on this and I can't understand how something so simple has taken up so much of my time. All I want to do it have the hasMany on the basket update when new Fruits are fetched!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the issue with rootState.loaded.updated.uncommitted. The issue here is that ember-data doesn't have a handler for the loadedData event whilst in that state. Unfortunately, there's no simple way to add an event, but I managed to do it by copying the closure that the original definition of the states was in. You can find more details here

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/extending-ember-data-states/838

And the working code is gisted here:

https://gist.github.com/pzuraq/5304796

I'm having a similar issue with hasMany relationships right now so I'm going to attempt to implement this and see if I can't get it working. I'll let you know if there is any progress on my end.